# "this is really helpful" or "that is really helpful" or "it is really helpful"

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Are they all correct? And what's the difference between them:

> 1. **This** is really helpful
> 2. **That** is really helpful
> 3. **It** is really helpful

Answer (score 2):

"This" and "that" are [demonstrative pronouns](https://7esl.com/demonstrative-pronouns-this-that-these-those/) that you would generally use to refer to something that is respectively near to or far from yourself. You would use one of those if you are not also stating the word it refers to.

"It" is a third-person pronoun used to refer to a specific thing, which typically should be clearly stated.

The context of the statement should tell you which pronoun to use, as in these examples:

**Jim held up a book. "This is really helpful."**

**Jim pointed at a book on the shelf. "That is really helpful."**

**Jim said, "I like this book. It is really helpful."**